# Print columns of text without hard coding the width

Tags: java, strings, column

If you'd like to print this:

```
One Two Three Four
 1   2    3    4
```

using this:

```
new Columns()
    .withColumnSeparator(" ")
    .withPad(" ")
    .alignCenter()
    .addLine("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
    .addLine("1", "2", "3", "4")
    .print()
;
```

all you need is this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.function.BiFunction;

public class Columns {

    List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> maxLengths = new ArrayList<>();
    int numColumns;
    int oldLength;
    boolean firstCall = true;
    String columnSeparator = " ";
    String pad = " ";
    BiFunction<String, String, String> align = (word, pad) -> word += pad;

    public Columns addLine(String... line) {

        if (firstCall){
            for(int column = 0; column < line.length; column++) {
                maxLengths.add(0);
            }
            oldLength = line.length;
        }
        
        if (oldLength != line.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        for(int column = 0; column < line.length; column++) {
            int length = Math
                .max( 
                    maxLengths.get(column), 
                    line[column].length() 
                )
            ;
            maxLengths.set( column, length );
        }

        lines.add( Arrays.asList(line) );
        firstCall = false;
        return this;
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println( toString() );
    }

    public String toString(){
        String result = "";
        for(List<String> line : lines) {
            for(int column = 0; column < line.size(); column++) {
                result += pad( line.get(column), maxLengths.get(column) );
                if (column < line.size() - 1) { 
                    result += columnSeparator; 
                }
            }
            result += System.lineSeparator();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String pad(String word, int newLength){
        while (word.length() < newLength) {
            word = align.apply(word, pad);
        }       
        return word;
    }

    public Columns withColumnSeparator(String columnSeparator){
        this.columnSeparator = columnSeparator;
        return this;
    }
        
    public Columns withPad(String pad){
        this.pad = pad;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Columns alignLeft(){
        align = (word, pad) -> word = word + pad;
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignRight(){
        align = (word, pad) -> word = pad + word;
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignCenter(){
        align = (word, pad) -> {
            return (word.length() % 2 == 0) 
                ? pad + word
                : word + pad
            ;
        };
        return this;
    }
}
```

By waiting until all the lines have been added before printing it can figure out the width each column needs.

Looking for a code review to reveal problems. Anything from better names to fewer bugs to better ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is good, and on the first look I don't see any bugs, but the implementation is a bit strange.

---

All fields are lacking a `private` modifier.

---

Some of the lambdas have an unnessecary assignment:

```
(word, pad) -> word = word + pad
(word, pad) -> word += pad
```

The assignment to the parameter `word` does nothing. Just

```
(word, pad) -> word + pad
```

is needed. You do it correctly in the "center" lamdba.

---

Also assigning "new" lambdas everywhere isn't very optimal. The lambdas should either be `static` constants or `private` methods:

```
private static final BiFunction<String, String, String> ALIGN_RIGHT = (word, pad) -> word + pad;

private BiFunction<String, String, String> align = ALIGN_RIGHT;

public Columns alignRight() {
    align = ALIGN_RIGHT;
    return this;
}
```

or

```
private BiFunction<String, String, String> = Columns::doAlignRight;

// TODO `doAlignRight` isn't a good name. Find better.
private static String doAlignRight(String word, String pad) {
    return word + pad;
}

public Columns alignRight() {
    align = Columns::doAlignRight;
    return this;
}
```

EDIT: In Java lambdas are just to short way to implement and instantiate an interface. For example:

```
align = (word, pad) -> word + pad;
```

in the method `alignRight()` is short for

```
align = new BiFunction<String, String, String>() {
    public String apply(String word, String pad) {
        return word + pad;
    }
};
```

In other words, everytime one one of the `align...` methods is called a new object is created. However this is unnessecary, because the objects are the same every time. Instead by, for example, keeping a single instance in a static variable and reusing them, much less memory management is needed.

---

Method names could be a bit better.

`with...` usually implies that a new instance (of a usually immutable class) is returned. `set...` would be better.

The `align...()`  methods should also start with `set...` to match the other configuration methods.

It can be confusing that there is both a field and a method called `pad`.

---

The field `numColumns` is not used. `firstCall` and `oldLength` isn't really needed. Instead of `firstCall` it could be checked if `lines` is empty, and when not use the length of one of its entries instead of `oldLength`.

---

String concatenation shouldn't be used in loops. A `StringBuilder` would be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks for the review. I'm struggling this assessment of lambdas. Either option seems to force me to use twice the names and I can't quiet see what it's getting me. Can you point to something?

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand what you are asking, but I've added some more explaination.

Comment: You're correct about it creating a new object. However, this is not anymore cpu expensive than pointer addition. It does have a memory cost but it's BigO(1) since there is no loop here to grow n. The new only happens when the lambda is set. Not when its method is called. Given that I prioritized making it easy to read. Did I miss something?

Comment: You are right. To be honest what mostly disturbed me was the duplicate "align right" lambda, and I just went a step further.

Comment: You were completely right about assigning to `word` in the lambdas. Was leftover noise from a refactoring.  By 'duplicate "align right"' do you mean the default initialization of `align`?

Comment: You may want to check out my [second attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283953/40367) at this following your feedback. I took a stab at making the default initialization cleaner.