# Print columns of text without hard coding the width (attempt 2)

Tags: java, strings, lambda, column

If you'd like to print this:

```
One Two Three Four
 1   2    3    4
```

using this:

```java
new Columns()
    .withColumnSeparator(" ")
    .withPad(" ")
//    .alignLeft()        
    .alignCenter()
//    .alignRight()
    .addLine("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
    .addLine("1", "2", "3", "4")
    .print()
;
```

all you need is this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;  
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;

public class Columns {

    private List<List<String>> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> maxLengths = new ArrayList<>();    
    private String columnSeparator = " ";
    private String pad = " ";
    private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> align;

    {
        alignLeft(); // set default alignment
    }

    public Columns addLine(String... line) {
        
        if (maxLengths.size() == 0){
            for(int column = 0; column < line.length; column++) {
                maxLengths.add(0);
            }
        }
        
        if ( maxLengths.size() != line.length ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        for(int column = 0; column < line.length; column++) {
            int length = Math
                .max( 
                    maxLengths.get(column), 
                    line[column].length() 
                )
            ;
            maxLengths.set( column, length );
        }

        lines.add( Arrays.asList(line) );
        return this;
    }

    public Columns print(){
        System.out.println( toString() );
        return this;
    }

    public String toString(){
        int totalLength = 0;
        
        for(List<String> line : lines) {
            for(int column = 0; column < line.size(); column++) {
                totalLength += maxLengths.get(column);
                if (column < line.size() - 1) { 
                    totalLength += columnSeparator.length(); 
                }
            }
            totalLength += System.lineSeparator().length();
        }
        
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(totalLength);
        
        for(List<String> line : lines) {
            for(int column = 0; column < line.size(); column++) {
                result.append(
                    padCell( 
                        line.get(column), 
                        maxLengths.get(column) 
                    )
                );
                
                if (column < line.size() - 1) { 
                    result.append(columnSeparator); 
                }
            }
            result.append( System.lineSeparator() );
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    private String padCell(String word, int newLength){
        int padCount = newLength - word.length();
        int leftCount = padCount / 2;
        int rightCount = padCount - leftCount;
        String left = new String(new char[leftCount]).replace("\0", pad);
        String right = new String(new char[rightCount]).replace("\0", pad);
        return align.apply(left).apply(word).apply(right);
    }

    public Columns separateColumnsWith(String columnSeparator){
        this.columnSeparator = columnSeparator;
        return this;
    }
        
    public Columns padWith(String pad){
        this.pad = pad;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Columns alignLeft(){
        align = left -> word -> right -> word + left + right;
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignCenter(){
        align = left -> word -> right -> left + word + right;
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignRight(){
        align = left -> word -> right -> left + right + word;
        return this;
    }
}
```

By waiting until all the lines have been added before printing it can figure out the width each column needs.

Looking for a code review to reveal problems. Anything from better names to fewer bugs to better ideas.

Along with some minor fixes the string concatenation has been [modified](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283924/40367) which simplified the alignment lambdas (and lengthened `padCell()` and `toString()`). Micro-optimization?

Comment: Nice! I really like the Builder pattern. The use of whitespace is a bit idiosyncratic, but I'm sure Jalopy or similar could tidy it up when incorporating this into another codebase. More `/**` comments _would_ be welcome. LGTM, ship it!

Comment: @J_H Or you could tidy up the codebase. Properly showing structure with white space rather than surrendering to word wrapped noise may be idiosyncratic [but that doesn't make it bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366355/readability-versus-maintainability-special-case-of-writing-nested-function-call/366370#366370). I guess some will always prefer blindly using tools instead of good judgement.

Comment: @J_H failing that, well, //@formatting:off, exists for a reason.

Comment: I have rolled back Rev 3 → 2. Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Did you consider creating an internal class for a single Column? I believe it would clean up the code considerably and also make adding functionality, like column-specific alignment, easier.

Comment: @TorbenPutkonen [I have now](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284061/print-columns-of-text-without-hard-coding-the-width-attempt-4). Please check it out and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are some interesting and inventive changes. Here are some thoughs (some new, some of which I missed - or just left out - last time):

First off, a bug: You are assuming that `pad` has a length of 1. I'd change it to a `char` or validate it in the setter.

---

I like the initialisation of `align` instead of the duplicate lambda.

The initializer block is an obscure feature and I believe, if there were multiple contructors its code is copied into each of them by the compiler creating artifical code duplicate. That's why I'd personally put it into a constructor, but I guess in this case the initializer block is fine, too.

---

Using a "curried" (is that the right word?) type to create the type of `align` is interesting. I guess it's fine here, but if the type would be needed at multiple locations this could become cumbersome. Personally I'd define my own `AlignFunction` functional interface.

---

In `addLine()` it may be sensibe to disallow lines with zero items. I can't see any immediate problems for that edge case, but it would avoid potential future problems.

An `else` between the two `if` would be good, because the two cases are exclusive.

The filling of `maxLength` could be done with [`Collections.nCopies()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,T)).

Actually thinking about it, I'd drop the `maxLength` field and just calculate the maximum lengths in the `toString` method.

---

I'd drop the `print()` method to avoid the unnecessary coupling with the console.

---

The calculation of the size of the `StringBuffer` is unnecessary IMO, but if you do it, you don't need to loop of the lines. It can be done with just summing up `maxLengths` and multiplication:

```
// Or just a loop. I prefer `Stream`s.
final int totalMaxLengths = maxLength.stream().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b); 

// TODO Format better
final int totalLength = (totalMaxLengths + columnSeparator.length() * (maxLengths.size() - 1) + System.lineSeparator().length()) * lines.size();
```

For the actual output building I suggested `StringBuilder` last time, but I'd probably also use `Stream`s.

---

The repeatition of strings in `padCell` is also interesting (you got it from Stackoverflow didn't you :) ). Since Java 11 however there is [`String::repeat()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#repeat(int)). Or at the very least extract the expression into a well named method.

Comment: Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ ♦ seems to be concerned I invalidated your answer by fixing the construction code. But I didn't see you mention `separateColumnsWith()` or `padWith()`. Since I'm not allowed to fix it, what do you think of the new names? I know you had concerns with the old ones.

Comment: Ah, I had forgotten to mention that: the names without the prefixes are better. The "With" suffix is a good idea, too.

Comment: You've inspired a [third attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/283990/40367)! And yes [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is when you break down a multi-arg function into a chain of partial single arg functions. Looks weird but it avoids the need to create a `TriFunction` interface.