# Print columns of text without hard coding the width (attempt 4)

Tags: java, lambda, column, inner-class

If you'd like to print this:

```
One Two Three Four 
1     2   3      4
```

using this:

```java
new Columns()
    .addLine("One", "Two", "Three", "Four")
    .addLine("1", "2", "3", "4")

    // .-={ Optional configuration examples }=-. //
    .separateColumnsWith(" ")
    .padWith(" ")
    .padWith(' ')
    .outputWith(System.out)
    .alignRight()
    .alignLeft(0)        
    .alignRight(1)
    .alignCenter(2)
    // '-={ Optional configuration examples }=-' //            

    .print()
;
```

all you need is this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;  
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.UnaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Columns {

    private final List<Column> columns = new ArrayList<>();

    // Defaults
    private String columnSeparator = " ";
    private String pad = " ";
    private PrintStream out = System.out;
    private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> align;

    {
        alignLeft(); // Set default alignment
    }

    public Columns addLine(String... line) {

        if ( columns.size() > 0 && columns.size() != line.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inconsistant arg. count.");
        }

        if ( columns.size() == 0 ) {
            for (int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) {
                columns.add( new Columns.Column(align) );
            }
        }
        
        IntStream
            .range(0, columns.size())
            .forEach( col -> columns.get(col).addWord(line[col]) )
        ;

        return this;
    }
    
    public Columns print(){
        out.println( toString() );
        return this;
    }

    public String toString(){
        
        final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        final int rows = columns.get(0).size();

        IntStream
            .range(0, rows)
            .forEach( 
                row -> {
                    result
                        .append( 
                            columns
                            .stream()
                            .map(col -> col.getCell(row))
                            .collect( Collectors.joining(columnSeparator) )
                        )
                    ;
                    result.append( System.lineSeparator() );
                }
            )
        ;

        return result.toString();
    }

   // .-={ Make defaults overridable }=-. //
   public Columns outputWith(PrintStream out){
        this.out = out;
        return this;
    }

    public Columns separateColumnsWith(String columnSeparator){
        this.columnSeparator = columnSeparator;
        return this;
    }
        
    public Columns padWith(String pad){
        if (pad.length() != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected single character");
        }
        this.pad = pad;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Columns padWith(char pad){
        this.pad = "" + pad;
        return this;
    }
    // '-={ Make defaults overridable }=-' //

    public Columns alignLeft(){
        align = getAlignLeft();
        columns.forEach(col -> col.setAlign(align));
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignCenter(){
        align = getAlignCenter();
        columns.forEach(col -> col.setAlign(align));
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignRight(){
        align = getAlignRight();
        columns.forEach(col -> col.setAlign(align));
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignLeft(int col){
        columns.get(col).setAlign( getAlignLeft() );
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignCenter(int col){
        columns.get(col).setAlign( getAlignCenter() );
        return this;
    }

    public Columns alignRight(int col){
        columns.get(col).setAlign( getAlignRight() );
        return this;
    }

    private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> getAlignLeft(){
        return left -> word -> right -> word + left + right;
    }

    private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> getAlignCenter(){
        return left -> word -> right -> left + word + right;
    }

    private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> getAlignRight(){
        return left -> word -> right -> left + right + word;
    }

    class Column {
        private List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
        private int maxLength = 0;
        private Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> align;

        public Column(Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> align){
            this.align = align;
        }
        
        public Columns.Column addWord(String word){
            maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, word.length());
            words.add(word);
            return this;
        }
        
        public String getCell(int row){
            return padCell( words.get(row), maxLength );
        }
        
        private String padCell(String word, int newLength){
            int padCount = newLength - word.length();
            int leftCount = padCount / 2;
            int rightCount = padCount - leftCount;
            String left = pad.repeat(leftCount);
            String right = pad.repeat(rightCount);
            return align.apply(left).apply(word).apply(right);
        }
        
        public int size(){
            return words.size();
        }
        
        public String toString(){
            return words.toString();
        }
        
        public Column setAlign(Function<String, Function<String, UnaryOperator<String>>> align){
            this.align = align;
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

By waiting until all the lines have been added before printing it can figure out the width each column needs.

Looking for a code review to reveal problems. Anything from better names to fewer bugs to better ideas.

Back on my [second attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283953/print-columns-of-text-without-hard-coding-the-width-attempt-2?noredirect=1#comment564694_283953) [@torbenputkonen](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12866/torbenputkonen) gave me [the idea of using an inner class for each column](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/283953/print-columns-of-text-without-hard-coding-the-width-attempt-2#comment564694_283953). As predicted it cleaned up the code and gave the flexibility to manage alignment on each column.

---

The reviews here have inspired a [5th attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284284/40367).

Comment: Happy to see another Orange 

Comment: @eccentricOrange likewise. There do seem to be [a fair number of us](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all&search=orange). Any thoughts on the code here?

Comment: Ah sorry, nope! I don't know Java sufficiently well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not wild about the `padWith(String)`, and restricting the string to a single character.  Just keep the `padWith(char)` method.

You can separate columns with `" | "`, but you can’t specify a prefix or suffix, so you can’t make vertical lines at the left and right edges.

While we’re at it, it might be nice to have top/bottom lines possible, and perhaps a line after headings.  But if you go too far down that rabbit hole, you’d probably want to call the class `Table`.

`.print().addLine(…).print()` has unexpected behaviour.  I don’t see the point of allowing anything to chain after doing a print unless it clears the accumulated buffer.  Perhaps it should be `void`.

Comment: Thank you for the review. You'll find some of your ideas implemented in my [5th attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284284/40367).

Answer (score 1):

This is getting interesting.

---

The `Column` class is a good idea. Maybe it's worth considering going even a step further and using a grid of "cells", allowing different alignments per row, too.

---

I'm still not a fan of tying this to a `PrintStream`. Specifically I don't see the point of the `out` field. I'd just pass the `PrintStream` as a parameter to the `print()` method.

---

And the curried functional interface is still quite clunky. It doesn't need to be a generic `TriFunction<A, B, C, R>` like you said last time, but it should be a specific `AlignFunction`.

---

While I normally like the use of `Stream`s, using an `IntStream` just with `forEach`, is IMO a bit pointless. Unfortunatly I can't think of a better way  due to Java's `Stream` API limits. At the least I'd replace the `StringBuilder` in `toString` with another joining `Collector`.

---

The `getAlign*` methods should be replaced by constants.

Comment: Thanks for the review. After 10 days I started to worry no one could read it. By `AlignFunction` I presume you mean something like: `@FunctionalInterface interface Alignment { String align(String left, String word, String right); }`

Comment: As you suggested, I managed to drop `StringBuilder` and use another joining `Collector` See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75892955/1493294).

Comment: As for the `out` field, I'm trying to decouple code that knows where to send this string from code that knows when. Can't do that if `out` is passed to the `print()` method. I'd prefer to keep configuration code separate from behavior code.

Comment: Thank you for the review. You'll find some of your ideas implemented in my [5th attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284284/40367).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I overthought your current solution. But after a while it confused me that the name of the class is `Columns` but we are adding lines/rows to it. If the class name were `Table` everything would be right. But because its name is `Columns` I await that we are adding columns to it, like in the following API:

```java
new Columns()
    .add("One", "1")
    .add("Two", "2")
    .add("Three", "3")
    .add("Four", "4")

    // .-={ Optional configuration examples }=-. //
    .separateColumnsWith(" ")
    .padWith(" ")
    .padWith(' ')
    .outputWith(System.out)
    .alignRight()
    .alignLeft(0)        
    .alignRight(1)
    .alignCenter(2)
    // '-={ Optional configuration examples }=-' // 

    .print()
```

This change on the API would simplify the method `addLine` (which I renamed to `add`):

```java
public Columns add(String... values) {
    if (columns.size() > 0 && columns.size() != values.length) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Inconsistant arg. count.");
    }
    
    Column column = new Columns.Column(align);

    for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        column.addWord(values[i]);
    }

    columns.add(column);    

    return this;
}
```

Because of the change of the API, I asked my self, if the methods `alignCenter`, `alignRight` and `alignLeft` still belong to `Columns`. Maybe they fit better into "`Column`". This would reduce the amount of methods a person needs to know. It is for me personally more intuitive too:

```java
new Columns()
    .add(Column.alignedLeft("One", "1"))
    .add(Column.alignedRight("Two", "2"))
    .add(Column.alignedCentered("Three", "3"))
    .add(Column.alignedRight("Four", "4"))

    // .-={ Optional configuration examples }=-. //
    .separateColumnsWith(" ")
    .padWith(" ")
    .padWith(' ')
    .outputWith(System.out)
    // '-={ Optional configuration examples }=-' // 

    .print()
```

Comment: You have a point about the name. Just not seeing  as much need for the pivoted interface. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Thank you for the review. You'll find some of your ideas implemented in my [5th attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284284/40367).

Comment: Couldn't stop thinking about your interface. You'll now find `Table` has a `toPivot()` method in my [6th attempt](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/284345/40367).